# Python script to send a notification on Widows

Tags: python, windows, replit

I want a Python script running on repl.it to send a notification to my Windows PC. How can I achieve this? The script runs 24/7 in REPL, I want it to send a notification to my PC if it's online when a value becomes True.

Answer (score 1):

The library `win10toast` has this feature. After installing through `pip` try:

```py
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
toast = ToastNotifier()
toast.show_toast("Hello, World!")
```

`show_toast` has other args for body, duration and icon.

Comment: But how do I make it so that when a value in my Python script running in a virtual server turns true, it sends a notification on my Windows laptop that is online. The script is not running on my local system.

Comment: You could use an email library and have the repl script send an email upon completion. There are quite a few existing well-documented email packages.

Comment: Fair. I was looking for a Windows Notification service but thanks regardless.